# Joomla URL Rewriting works automatically in Nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite, php-fpm, joomla

This is driving me nuts and I dont understand how this works automatically. I have nginx as my web server and I have installed Joomla that has URL Rewriting which removes the `index.php` from the URL. Before, when I was using Apache, I have to enable the .htaccess with `RewriteEngine On` in order for this to work. But with Nginx, when I enable "Use URL Rewriting" it works automatically. I only use Nginx that passes the php files to php-fpm. Thats all. I havent added any special rewrite rule other than what was given in Joomla docs. I dont understand how 'Use URL Rewriting' just works automatically  when I enable it since there is no .htaccess for Nginx.

The [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs_on_Nginx) on this topic didint help neither. In second step it says

> Enable the Use Apache mod_rewrite/URL rewriting option and Save: This
>   option uses the Apache mod_rewrite function to eliminate the
>   "index.php" portion of the URL.
>
> .....
>
> If this option causes errors, please see How to check if mod rewrite
>   is enabled on your server. If it is not enabled and you have access to
>   the file apache/conf/httpd.conf, open that file and check if the line
>   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented. If
>   necessary, uncomment the line and restart the Apache web server.

No idea why this is added in an Nginx configuration since there is no mod_rewrite in Nginx. The URL Rewriting in Joomla backend says this:

> Use URL rewriting Select to use a server's rewrite engine to catch
>   URLs that meet specific conditions and rewrite them as directed.
>   Available for IIS 7 and Apache.  Apache users only! Rename
>   htaccess.txt to .htaccess before activating. Rename web.config.txt to
>   web.config and install IIS URL Rewrite Module before activating.

It says nothing about Nginx but still it works. I am scratching my head here. Can someone tell me how the Joomla's index.php is removed so easily in Nginx? This is my Nginx Vhost configuration:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/example/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/accn_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/accn_error.log;

        ##
        # JOOMLA SEF
        ##

        location / {
              try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
        }

        ##
        # PHP scripts to FastCGI 
        ##
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

See.. its a pretty straight forward configuration. Where is the magic happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic happens here:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
```

This means that nginx checks first if the requested file or directory exists on the filesystem. If a file does not exist, it passes the request to Joomla, and passing the original URI to the `q` parameter.

Comment: okay..that make sense. But how is the `index.php` removed from the url leaving just the query parameter? Is that completely controlled by Joomla and no need for special rewrite rule in nginx config?

Comment: `index.php` isn't really removed at all. The processing is passed to `index.php` (first part of URI) like a normal web request would be. The `index.php` then receives the `q` parameter.

Comment: aha.. so thats why it works straight away. Make sense now. It also seems a lot easier than what I used to do with Apache. Also the Joomla docs is wrong then.. thats what started confusing me more... Thank you @TiroKilkanen for explaining. :)